# How to change the system font inter-letter spacing?

Tags: fonts, gnome-tweak-tool

I set my system font to 'aakar medium' in [gnome-tweaks](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Tweaks). Now the letters in a word are a bit closer to each other. There's [no bug reported](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-tweaks/issues) for this issue. Is there anything I can do to change the [kerning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning), or inter-letter spacing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this may just be a feature of the font itself in your gnome environment. I believe it is possible (at least on certain Mac environments) to increase letter/font spacing by editing your `gnome.css` (or, maybe `gtk.css`) stylesheet but I am not clear on how this method works or if it is still possible in the latest release of gnome/gtk. Try resizing the terminal or adjusting your desktop resolution to see if the problem persists.